# Discussion about bash screen managers -t option usage

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I was working with `screen` lately and wanted to use the `-t` option for it. What's the point of the`-t` option if the title of the screen does not show anywhere like when using `-list` or within the screen when it's attached?

There is a command `CTRL-A double-quote(")` to see all active screens, and then it shows the title, but that does not really do the job, because I have to have the screen attached already. I want to read out the title BEFORE attaching any screens, to attach the right one in the first place.

Is there a method to use `-t` in a convenient way?

Edit:
There is one method: `ctrl-a "` and then `ctrl-a {numberofscreen}`. I guess that's the best way to use the screen titles?

Edit2:
It seems I was using screen incorrectly. I mixed up windows with instances of screen. Better usage (for me): use the same screen (with `screen -r`) and create windows within, which I then can name and list using one of the several methods.
To sum it up:
The title `-t` is not the screen title, but the WINDOW title.
Thank you for the discussion!

Edit3:
I just found out: The names which are shown in `screen -list` are the Session names. The command would be `screen -S "sessionname"` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctl-a w` will show a list of all the screens at the bottom of the window, with the titles you assigned in place of the command.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly,

1) "-t" is merely a convenience to allow you to more easily identify screens you've created.  It's entirely optional.

2) You can see what screens you've created (including their "-t" titles) with `screen -ls`.

Here are a couple of tutorials:

- http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6340

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yes, the option is optional. It just seems not logical to me that "screen -ls" does not show the titles. I've read several tutorials and the man page, I was curious if theres a "quick" way, a nice workflow for the title usage.

Comment: One other suggestion: `ls -laR /var/run/screen/`  PS: I thought "screen -ls" *did* list the titles.  Sorry.  I agree with you about "illogical" ;).  Please let us know if the "ls /var/run/screen" works for you.

Comment: After a bit of gambling: Screen can have several instances, which can be listed with "screen -ls". Each instance can have multiple windows, which you can name, or give titles to. by calling "screen -t 'somename'" you name the first window of your new screen instance, and not the instance itself. Is that correct?

@paulsm4
ls /var/run/screen/ just gave me a list of users... eg.: "S-alex", etc... does not seem to show screen titles.

Comment: It seems I was using screen incorrectly. I mixed up windows with instances of screen.
Better usage (for me): use the same screen (with "screen -r") and create windows within, which I then can name and list using one of the several methods.
Thank you for the discussion!